# Assigning Functions from other Classes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to access and run a specific method/function from another class that can change dynamically as the app is run?

I’ll try to simplify the problem as much as possible.

**SelectionPage.swift**

Choose which class needs to be selected and accessed using an UIPickerView - 10 possible selections (Class1, Class2, Class3,…, Class10).

**Class1.swift, Class2.swift, … Class10.swift**

Each of the 10 classes has a single method that has exactly the same name but is programmed differently:

```
func runOnUpdate() { }
```

**GameSceneViewController.swift**

When a selection is made on the SelectionPage, the app segues to a GameSceneViewController where the specific selected function is run every time the update function is run:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) 
{ 
    // run runOnUpdate() function here from selected class
}
```

Inside the update function, I would like to execute the runOnUpdate( ) function depending on which class was selected on the SelectionPage. Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to be able to assign the specific class/method in the:

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
```

so that I can access in other functions as well.

I’ve looked into lazy instantiation, creating delegates for each of the classes, @objc(Class1), arrays of [AnyClass], typealias, global variables in structs, singletons etc. but I’m unable to figure out how to make this work.

It seems like a fairly common problem so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct in trying delegates as this is a case where you should make a protocol and a delegate. The protocol requires the function. From there you set the delegate property to an instance of a class that conforms to that protocol and then you call `delegate?.someFunction()` to call the function on the given object.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: Updatable?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let foo = Foo()
        delegate = foo
        delegate?.runOnUpdate() // prints do something
    }
}


protocol Updatable {
    func runOnUpdate()
}

class Foo: NSObject, Updatable {
    func runOnUpdate() {
        println("do something")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved the problem. One more question.... is it possible to make the variable 'foo' (set to the instance of the Foo() class) accessible outside the scope of the viewDidLoad() function? I'm wondering if there is a way to clean up my code so I don't use a massive if statement to decide which class foo should be assigned to (Class1, Class2, etc.)? I've tried to dynamically set the NSClassFromString but without any luck.